# Dependency problems while installing wine 7.0 on Mint 20.04

Tags: linux-mint, wine

I'm trying to install winehq-stable package version 7.0.0, but I'm getting a dependency problem that I'm not managed to solve yet. It says that winehq-stable depends on wine-stable (=7.0.0~focal-1), if I try to install both by hand the problem goes on and on in an infinite loop of dependencies, so I tried to manually pass those packages to apt install command resulting in this:

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable wine-stable wine-stable- i386 libsane:i386 libsnmp35:i386 libmysqlclient21:i386 mysql-common:i386 mysql-common
```

The output was this one:

```
The package mysql-common:i386 is a virtual package provided by:
mysql-common 5.8+1.0.5ubuntu2[not a candidate version]

E: The package 'mysql-common:i386' doesn't have a candidate for installation
```

I tried everything I know to try to solve those dependencies, but I couldn't find an answer. What I'm I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wrong.  It has nothing to do with the Mint flavor.  I filed a bug report with WineHQ and the moderator wrote back that it had to do with having a version of mysql-common that was more recent than the version required by wine:

> For Ubuntu users, this type of problem usually happens when they've
> installed packages from a PPA. In the case of Mint, it's also possible
> packages in the Mint repository that differ from the Ubuntu ones are
> causing the problem. Either way, it's not a bug. WineHQ packages are
> built against dependencies in the standard and universe Ubuntu
> repositories, and that's the only configuration that is supported. As
> you noted yourself, you were able to install Wine on a laptop running
> Mint, so the problem is something installed on the problem systems.

Sure enough, I had a more recent version of MariaDB (which uses mysql-common) than the one distributed by the "official" Ubuntu repository.  The solution was found in the comments section of an earlier bug report ([https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=52011).  You have to downgrade mysql-common.  Before installing Wine 7.0, enter:

`sudo apt install mysql-common=5.8+1.0.5ubuntu`

That did the trick.  MariaDB still seems to work without any problems after the downgrade.  However, you might want to put a hold on mysql-common (sudo apt hold mysql-common) or you'll get nagged to upgrade every time you do an apt update.

Comment: I made a linux mint clean installation, and then I installed following the instruction in winehq's site and it installed normally. Trying to put MariaDB official PPA to install latest version, and install MariaDB, apt suggested the wine packages removal along with other packages. Thing is, this dependency on MySQL libraries are limiting wine installation on systems with older packages and, sometimes, you'll have to stick with newer ones.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how mysql could be related to installing wine. It has nothing to do with it. Start over with these commands

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 

sudo apt update

sudo apt install software-properties-common wget curl

wget -qO - https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main'

sudo apt update

sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

And that should be more than enough.

Comment: I tried it, I followed strictly what was in winehq installation instruction, but it didn't work indicating the problem I told, so every package that was appearing after the apt install as a dependency problem, I appended to install manually as shown in my question. The last one that appeared was mysql related and neither me could understand why it was asking for mysql libraries. That's why I told that I couldn't find any conventional way to solve it, as I tried everything I know and found in numerous forums.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what flavor of Mint you're using (Cinnamon, Mate, Xfce).  If you're trying to install it on Linux Mint 20.03 (or 20.02) with the Cinnamon desktop you're out of luck.  Wine 7 won't install (or upgrade from Wine 6.02) on Mint 20.03 or 20.02 Cinnamon no matter what you do.  There's a bug, either in Cinnamon or the Wine 7 installation files, that prevents installation.  And the dependency errors reported make no sense (e.g. mysql-common) since the missing files aren't in either the Ubuntu or Mint repositories.  I tried every possible way, both as an upgrade and a clean install (including Alex's solution above), and tried with Mint 20.02 as well as 20.03 on two separate computers.  However I did successfully install it using Alex's recommendation on a laptop running Mint 20.03 with the Xfce desktop.  Go figure.